# Counting comparisons on insertion sort

Tags: python, comparison, insertion-sort

I'm having difficulty trying to figure out just how to create a counter for my insertion sort in which it counts the number of comparisons the insertion sort makes.

In short id like to figure out how I can count all comparisons , even those in the while loop and in the for loop.

```
import random

class sorting:

    alist = []
    # 10 random numbers between 10 and 70
    for i in range(10):
        # integer random numbers between 10 and 70
        n = random.randint(10, 70)
        alist.append(n)
    print(alist)

    def insertionSort(alist,):
        for index in range(1, len(alist)):

            currentvalue = alist[index]
            position = index

            while position > 0 and alist[position - 1] > currentvalue:
                alist[position] = alist[position - 1]
                position = position - 1

            alist[position] = currentvalue

    insertionSort(alist)
```

Comment: Maybe keep a `count` variable, add 2 inside the while-loop, and an extra 2 when you exit?

Comment: would this code be correct ?

Answer (score 0):

would this be correct ?

```
import random
```

class sorting:

```
alist = []
# 10 random numbers between 10 and 70
for i in range(2):
    # integer random numbers between 10 and 70
    n = random.randint(10, 70)
    alist.append(n)
print(alist)



def insertionSort(alist):
    count = 0
    for index in range(1, len(alist)):

        currentvalue = alist[index]

        position = index

        while position > 0 and alist[position - 1] > currentvalue:
            alist[position] = alist[position - 1]
            position = position - 1
            count +=1


        alist[position] = currentvalue
    count += 1
    print(count)


insertionSort(alist)
```

Comment: Yes that's close enough with little modification, add 2 to the counter because we are making two comparisons every time. I have posted the answer above, if it helps please mark as answer or vote it.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a counter and keep it count as suggested in the comments. Final code looks as follows

```
import random

class sorting:

alist = []
# 10 random numbers between 10 and 70
for i in range(10):
    # integer random numbers between 10 and 70
    n = random.randint(10, 70)
    alist.append(n)
print(alist)

def insertionSort(alist,):
    counter=0
    for index in range(1, len(alist)):

        currentvalue = alist[index]
        position = index
        counter +=2  # For the case postion <0 ........
        while position > 0 and alist[position - 1] > currentvalue:
            counter +=2
            alist[position] = alist[position - 1]
            position = position - 1

        alist[position] = currentvalue
    print(counter)
insertionSort(alist)
```